# fastapi - async download an excel file FileResponse

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi

I'm using a pre-filled Excel range to overwrite it with editpyxl. I saw that openpyxl and xlsxwriter are not able (yet) to keep shapes etc. in other sheets when another sheet is written.

And editpyxl takes a lot of time to write to the Excel range. However, it also blocks the application so I'm trying to make it asynchronous, but wasn't able yet as using `await` doesn't just work out of the box like magic..

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from fastapi.responses import FileResponse
import editpyxl

app = FastAPI()

temp_folder = "./_temp"
file_output_name = "output_fileresponse.xlsx"

@app.get("/my-projects/{project}/download-report", include_in_schema=False)
async def my_project(request: Request,
                     project: str, ):
    report_template = Path(path, excel_file)
    wb = editpyxl.Workbook()
    wb.open(report_template)
    ws = wb.active

    def write_pd_to_xlsx(xlsx_range, pd_series):
        ss = ws.cells_in_range(xlsx_range)
        sc = df[pd_series]
        zipped_lists = zip(ss, sc)
        for xlsx_cell, pd_value in zipped_lists:
            ws.cell(xlsx_cell).value = pd_value

    total_records = 2000

    ranges_excel_file = [f"C8:C{total_records + 7}", f"D8:D{total_records + 7}", 
                         f"E8:E{total_records + 7}", f"F8:F{total_records + 7}",]
    
    columns_to_use = ["Column 1", "Column 2", "Column 3", "Column 4"]

    zipped_ranges_columns = zip(ranges_excel_file, columns_to_use)
    for rng, col in zipped_ranges_columns:
        write_pd_to_xlsx(rng, col)
        
    wb.save(os.path.join(temp_folder, file_output_name))
    
    response = FileResponse(os.path.join(temp_folder, file_output_name), filename=file_output_name)
    wb.close()
    
    return response
```

Comment: It seems to me that the best solution would be to separate the file preparation process from the download method. Create a file preparation route and run it in a new thread. This will not block the asynchronous loop. Check the preparation status and upload the file after preparation is complete.

Comment: Interesting advice!! I'll have a look and excited to see how to implement this.